# Spring Boot 2, how can I set eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication false in ProviderManager

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I use spring boot 2 + Spring Security 5. I don't want to erase credentials after authentication, so I want to set `eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication = false` in `ProviderManger`. But I don't know how to configure it in Spring Boot without XML configuration.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, I know it. Just configure in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

```java
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.eraseCredentials(false);
    }

}
```